# Ionic 3 Stripe Elements: iOS keyboard close when the card number is complete and the focus goes to the input date

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, stripe-payments

When inputting card details using stripe elements on an Ionic app, can't keep the keyboard focus on the card entry fields.

I've tried solutions in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46592848/ionic-and-stripe-elements-keyboard-bug-with-ios) but no luck

This is the code I've implemented

```
this.card = elements.create("card", { style });
this.card.focus();
setTimeout(() => {
  this.card.blur();
});

this.card.mount(this.cardInfo.nativeElement);

this.card.addEventListener("change", this.cardHandler);
// With element being a reference to the card element created by stripe.elements()
// or the CardElement component.
this.card.addEventListener("blur", ev => {
  // Apply only as a workaround for Safari on iOS,
  // else it will create an infinite loop on the `blur` event.
  if (
    navigator.userAgent.search("iPhone") != -1 &&
    navigator.userAgent.search("Version/") != -1
  ) {
    this.card.focus();
    this.card.blur();
  }

  // This is mandatory for all browsers
  this.card.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].blur();
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question and add some code?

Comment: I've updated the post now

Comment: I am also facing same issue on IOS device with stripe v2 element integrated in ionic v1. Did you find any solution?